# How to check if CacheConnection failed

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following C#:

```
string Connectioncacha = "";

CacheConnection CacheConnect = new CacheConnection();
CacheConnect.ConnectionString = Connectioncacha;
CacheConnect.Open();

if (CacheConnect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    return "working";
}
else
{
    return "no data";
}
```

The issue is, if the connection fails it fails in the `CacheConnect.Open()` and throws an error.

How can I modify the code so that in case the connection fails, rather than showing a page error, it just sends the text `no data` back to the client?

Comment: Why not just `catch (TheSpecificException ex) { ... }`

Comment: This might help more. I found this pdf that fully explains what you're trying to do. http://docs.intersystems.com/documentation/cache/20102/pdfs/GBMP.pdf

Comment: Never heard of a widely knwon "CacheConnection"-class in realm of C# and SQL (I assume you mean ADO.NET?). Are your tags properly set?

Answer (score 2):

Surround it with a try/catch statement

```
    try 
    {
      string Connectioncacha = "";

      CacheConnection CacheConnect = new CacheConnection();
      CacheConnect.ConnectionString = Connectioncacha;
      CacheConnect.Open();

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {

       if (CacheConnect)
           CacheConnect.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I would replace `Exception` with whatever the connection failed exception is so you don't swallow things you need to know about

Comment: @AlexK. Sure you can if you want to be more specific.

Comment: @gmlacrosse, it goes into the TRY statement and goes to the `.Open()` and stays there for a very long and then finally hits the `catch`. Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: So if I have to call the class 5 times, it adds up. Is there anyway to check it once?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge You can try going with using(CacheConnnection CacheConnect = new CacheConnection) {} inside of the try/catch.

Comment: It seems the `.Open()` is where it takes a while before going to the catch statement. Any way to check before trying the `.Open()`?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I haven't found any code that is faster than this.

Comment: If TRY fails, there is no closing statement inside the CATCH.